# How to track time being spent in a chrome tab in react native

Tags: javascript, react-native, analytics, react-native-router-flux, chrome-custom-tabs

In my app I am using [react-native-custom-tabs](https://github.com/droibit/react-native-custom-tabs) with [react-native-router-flux](https://github.com/aksonov/react-native-router-flux)

I have two questions

1) When a user opens an article in custom chrome tab, I want to track how much time a user spent on that article.

2) How can we track when a user navigates to another app while reading and resumes reading?